# Refetch queries server side after a client side mutation apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo, server-side-rendering, apollo-client, next.js13

I'm using the experimental version of graphql and apollo client together with next13 and at one point in my code I perform a mutation in a client side component to delete data and I need the query that was performed in a server side component to be re-done for the list of results to be updated. How can I do this?

i am using the following code to do the queries and mutations in the server side components:

`const {data: userEvents} = await getClient().query()`

and the following code in client components:

`const [deleteEvent] = useMutation(DeleteEvent, { refetchQueries: [ { query: getAllUserEvents, variables: { userId: session?.user.id  } } ] })`

I need that when I perform the deletion mutation on the client side component the search query on the server side component is re-done.